# How can I group date from multiple rows into one in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables 'event' and 'club'. Since they have many to many relationship there is also a junction table 'club_event'. I created a view which holds all the columns in event table with the club_name from the club table that organized the event. The problem is that when a event has two or more organizing clubs there will be multiple copies of a entire row for that event in the view table. Rather than this I want different club_name to be kept as a comma separated values in columns. How may I do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_EVENT" ("EVENT_ID", "EVENT_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "START_TIME", "END_TIME", "DESCRIPTION", "FROM_COLLEGE", "FROM_COMMUNITY", "CLUB_NAME") AS 
  SELECT event."EVENT_ID",event."EVENT_NAME",event."START_DATE",event."END_DATE",event."START_TIME",event."END_TIME",event."DESCRIPTION",event."FROM_COLLEGE",event."FROM_COMMUNITY", club_name
FROM event
LEFT JOIN (club_event INNER JOIN club ON club_event.club_id = club.club_id)
ON event.event_id = club_event.event_id
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that query you wrote returns desired result.

`LISTAGG` function is nowaday used to do what you want - put all club names into a single column, separated by some separator (doesn't have to be a comma). As it *aggregates* result, you'll have to put all other non-aggregated columns into the `group by` clause.

Something like this:

```
create or replace force view v_event as 
  select e.event_id,
    e.event_name,
    e.start_date,
    e.end_date,
    e.start_time,
    e.end_time,
    e.description,
    e.from_college,
    e.from_community, 
    listagg(c.club_name, ',') within group (order by c.club_name) club_name
from event e
left join (club_event ce inner join club c on ce.club_id = c.club_id) 
  on e.event_id = ce.event_id
group by  
    e.event_id,
    e.event_name,
    e.start_date,
    e.end_date,
    e.start_time,
    e.end_time,
    e.description,
    e.from_college,
    e.from_community
/
```

---

Also, as we're using Oracle, get rid of double quotes; they cause nothing but problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please mention your Oracle version.
In Oracle 11g Release 2 LISTAGG was introduced making such a task very simple:

```
SELECT event."EVENT_ID"
      ,event."EVENT_NAME"
      ,event."START_DATE"
      ,event."END_DATE"
      ,event."START_TIME"
      ,event."END_TIME"
      ,event."DESCRIPTION"
      ,event."FROM_COLLEGE"
      ,event."FROM_COMMUNITY"
      ,LISTAGG(club_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY club_name) AS clubs
   FROM event
   LEFT JOIN (club_event INNER JOIN club ON club_event.club_id = club.club_id)
   ON event.event_id = club_event.event_id
   GROUP BY event."EVENT_ID"
      ,event."EVENT_NAME"
      ,event."START_DATE"
      ,event."END_DATE"
      ,event."START_TIME"
      ,event."END_TIME"
      ,event."DESCRIPTION"
      ,event."FROM_COLLEGE"
      ,event."FROM_COMMUNITY"
```

If you are running on a version prior you can try rolling out your own user defined aggregate function as described [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)

The GROUP BY Statement in SQL is used for aggregations. Since LISTAGG is an aggregate function the database needs to know which columns need to be grouped. In your case, it was all the columns you were selecting and which did not have an aggregation function applied.
The documentation of [aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) probably does a better job at explaining than I can.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had already used LISTAGG function similar to the way you have used it but I kept on getting 'not a single-group group function' error. This was because I didn't use GROUP BY. It would be of great help if you could explain why the need for GROUP BY command.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is not only simpler to write, but probably also has better performance because it avoids the outer aggregation:

```
SELECT . . .   -- the columns you want from event,
      (SELECT LISTAGG(c.club_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.club_name)
       FROM club_event ce INNER JOIN
            club c
            ON ce.club_id = c.club_id
       WHERE e.event_id = ce.event_id
      ) clubs
FROM event e;
```